# Retrieve value for specific key in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary like:

```
[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'Thomas'},{'Key':'Location', 'Value':'EMEA'}]
```

I want to retrieve the Value 'EMEA' if Key is 'Location'.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Dude, that's so useless and inefficient. Create a single dict, not a list of dict. You would have `{'Name': 'Thomas', 'Location': 'EMEA'}`

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension

```py
items = [{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'Thomas'},{'Key':'Location', 'Value':'EMEA'}]
res = [item['Value'] for item in items if item['Key'] == 'Location']

print(res)
```

Comment: @Diksha Agnihotri If it helps can you accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each dictionary:

```py
x = [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Thomas'}, {'Key': 'Location', 'Value': 'EMEA'}]

for entry in x:
    if entry["Key"] == "Location":
        print(entry["Value"])
```

```
EMEA
```

> [Further reading](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_access.asp)